# Validar formulario en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, validate

tengo un proyecto de hace meses, y ahora me pidieron hacer un proyecto, y pues, tome este y quiero mejorarlo, quisiera validar los campos vacíos, ósea, al dar al botón guardar, si el campo esta vacío, que me salte una alerta. La verdad, tengo mas o menos una idea, pero no se como empezar, dejo el código aquí:

```
function guardar(){
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Esta seguro que quieres guardar los cambios ?',
        showDenyButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'SI',
        denyButtonText: `NO`,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3999/api/paciente/save',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    idPaciente: $("#txtIdPaciente").val(),
                    nombres: $("#txtNombres").val(),
                    dni: $("#txtDni").val(),
                    direccion: $("#txtDireccion").val(),
                    especialidad: $("#txtEspecialidad").val(),
                    cita: $("#txtCita").val(),
                    estado: $("#cboEstado").val()


                },
                success: function (respuesta) {
                    console.log(respuesta);
                    listar();
                }


            });

            Swal.fire('Se guardaron los cambios!', '', 'success')
        } else if (result.isDenied) {
            Swal.fire('Cambios no guardados', '', 'info')
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Coloca el código como texto, de lo contrario cierran las preguntas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pones una Id en el form, digamos MyForm y teniendo en cuenta que:

Las validaciones HTML5 tienen 2 funciones importantes

- checkValidity: Retorna true o false
- reportValidity: Muestra la validación visualmente

Tú función guardar queda:

```
function guardar(){
 if(!MyForm.checkValidity()){
    MyForm.reportValidity();
 }
 else{
   //aqui el resto de tu código original
 }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya tengo la idea como terminarlo. Aun soy nuevo aquí, puse el código pero me salía error.